# Sendmail sends everything except for mails with recipients of the same domain

Tags: email-server, configuration, sendmail

I am using the following setup.

The client's DNS is pointing to Hostgator, but the client wants to test if his site runs faster on DigitalOcean. So the only DNS records I am pointing to DigitalOcean are:

```
site.com          A         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.site.com      CNAME     site.com
site.com          AAAA      abcd:abcd::::::0001 (example ip6)
```

The rest of the DNS records are pointed to the hostgator server.

I configured `sendmail` for mail sending from the site and everything works fine, until the destination address is `...@site.com`.

I am pretty sure it's considering the delivery as a local delivery and it's never sent outside of the server.

Here's my `sendmail.mc` file just the parts I've modified:

```
...
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
...
...
MAILER_DEFINITIONS   -- I haven't touched these three lines
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl


dnl define(`MAIL_HUB', `site.com.')dnl  
dnl define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `site.com.')dnl

LOCAL_RULESETS
LOCAL_RULE_0

define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `true')dnl

R$* < @site.com. > $*   $#esmtp $@ mail.site.com $: $1<@site.com.>$2
```

My `local-host-names` was originally:

```
site.com
localhost
```

Changed it to:

```
localhost
```

Also, my `/etc/hosts` file has this line:

```
127.0.0.1 site.com {servername} localhost.localdomain localhost
```

In this case `{servername}` is my server's local name.

Relevant `mail.log` entries:

```
Mar 23 01:36:13 servername sendmail[15492]: 02N1aD4f015492: from=www-data, size=5902, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<9c87adbbbcf9915930b16972d7b17b7e@site.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Mar 23 01:36:13 servername sm-mta[15493]: 02N1aDOf015493: <receiver@site.com>... User unknown
```

I think this log entry basically describes the situation. The **user unknown** part. The rest of the log entries are fine, this is the one that fails where the domain is `@site.com`.

I followed these tutorials, but it seems it's still not working:

1. https://tecadmin.net/install-sendmail-on-ubuntu/
2. http://biostall.com/how-i-resolved-my-ubuntu-sendmail-woes/

What should I modify in sendmail's config in order to indicate that the reception of e-mails is not done on that server?

Comment: Could you post the relevant entries in the log file?  Your description leaves far too many open possibillities.

Comment: Hello @AnFi I added parts of `sendmail.mc` and `local-host-names`.

Comment: I also added `etc/hosts`.

Comment: I have asked for (system) **log entries** generated by the failed deliveries.  Sorry but I am used to "misleading descriptions" and "big differences in terminology".

Comment: Hello again @AnFi sorry I misread your comment. I opened `/var/log/mail.log` and I updated my question with the entries I considered relevant to this case.

Comment: Could you also post results produced by `echo $j | sendmail -bt` (this host email name) and `echo $=w | sendmail -bt` (list of local email domains) and content of `/etc/mail/local-host-names` ("manual" list of local email domains)